# BigQuery: Weighted average

Tags: google-bigquery

Table:

```
| User_ID |  Red | Blue | Green |  Rating |
|   a     |   23 |  33  |   42  |    99   |
|   a     |   56 |  45  |   62  |    45   |
|   a     |   23 |  49  |   28  |    67   |
|   b     |   39 |  59  |   10  |    87   |
|   b     |   18 |  28  |   59  |    38   |
|   b     |   40 |  50  |   38  |    94   |
```

The result I want to obtain is a distinct row of user_id, with a weighted average of red, blue and green - based on the rating column.

colour * rating/(sum of rating for a or b)

//Edit

Can't wrap my head around how to do this. Tried the following but it was a futile attempt

```
   WITH
      averages AS (
      SELECT
        User_ID,
        SUM(rating) AS average
      FROM
`       project.dataset.table` 
      GROUP BY
        1)
    SELECT
      averages.User_ID,
      Red*(Rating/average),
      Blue*(rating/average),
      Green*(rating/average)
    FROM
      `project.dataset.table` a
    LEFT JOIN
      averages
    ON
      a.user_id = averages.user_id
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: have edited my response with the code i've tried :)

Answer (score 10):

I see - it's more a math problem. You multiply values with their weight and later divide not by the count, but by the sum of weights. Everything per group (user id). You can try something like `SELECT SUM(x * weight) / SUM(weight) FROM table GROUP BY ...`

```
WITH t AS (SELECT * FROM 
  UNNEST([
    STRUCT('a' AS userID, 23 AS red, 99 AS weight),
    STRUCT('a' AS userID, 56 AS red, 45 AS weight),
    STRUCT('a' AS userID, 23 AS red, 67 AS weight),
    STRUCT('b' AS userID, 39 AS red, 87 AS weight),
    STRUCT('b' AS userID, 18 AS red, 38 AS weight),
    STRUCT('b' AS userID, 40 AS red, 94 AS weight)
  ])
  )

SELECT
  userID,
  SUM(red*weight) / SUM(weight) weightedAvg,
  AVG(red) normalAvg
FROM
  t
GROUP BY
  userID
```

hth!

Answer (score 4):

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'a' User_ID, 23 Red, 33 Blue, 42 Green, 99 Rating UNION ALL
  SELECT 'a', 56, 45, 62, 45 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'a', 23, 49, 28, 67 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b', 39, 59, 10, 87 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b', 18, 28, 59, 38 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b', 40, 50, 38, 94 
)
SELECT User_ID,  
  CAST(SUM(Red * Rating) / SUM(Rating) AS INT64) Red,
  CAST(SUM(Blue * Rating) / SUM(Rating) AS INT64) Blue,
  CAST(SUM(Green * Rating) / SUM(Rating) AS INT64) Green
FROM `project.dataset.table` 
GROUP BY User_ID
```

with result

```
Row User_ID Red     Blue    Green    
1   a       30      41      42   
2   b       36      50      31
```